# Whay are senior UX leaders/gurus like Don Norman and Alan Cooper not on this community?

Tags: community

I understand that this might not be the right question to ask here - but I can't help but think that when mentors like **Don Norman** and **Alan Cooper** are regular on platforms like Linkedin and Twitter, why not on ux.stackexchange.com? There *opinions and experience* could help the community a lot. Can anyone from the community (who might have a reach to them) pass a message if possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't speak for individuals.

Comment: I understand and respect when community thinks that this is off-topic. Just thinking if we could move this to meta? And explore, if the community could have a facility for guest posts/comments/profile?

Answer (score 2):

In Russian, there is a saying "to hammer nails with your microscope" which means trying to resolve a mundane issue with much more precise, fragile and expensive tool.

The questions we read here are 80% routine, and only maybe 5% are interesting, debatable oddities, a specific cases that are up to the caliber of someone like them and could actually benefit from their opinion.

I suspect hanging around here would be a major waste of Norman's, Cooper's, Tufte's time.

And it also could be a huge intimidation for the mid-specialist people who are the majority of the community. It would not be easy to contribute your answer after Don Norman has answered it. It would be like trying to sell something to Elon Musk or showing your design to Ive.

Not that I would be intimidated personally by their presence. I just think that they both have more interesting things to do and have enough common sense to not to mingle among younger and less experienced people.

Comment: Perhaps you are right Zoe!

Comment: Too bad :-) I think this is a question that could trigger a big and interesting discussion ;-). I feel it belongs in meta, though.

Comment: Where I totally agree with what you say, my question/thought was intended towards expert opinions from them on 'Hot Questions' on the community perhaps? I think may be there could be a better way to tackle this and source their opinion - a guest entry may be? I was just thinking aloud if there could be a possibility there.

Comment: @AmitJain note that the 'hot questions' aren't usually 'good questions'.

Comment: @AmitJain This was just posted in one of my LinkedIn groups: chatting with Don Norman ;-) http://ux-radio.com/2015/12/reflections-design-everyday-things/